# SetWindowPos/MoveWindow persist issue

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, window-position

I am using `SetWindowPos` and `MoveWindow` to resize and center windows.  It works fine, but on several windows like Windows Media Player or Control Panel, when you close the window and open it again, the new resizing/moving is not reflected.  When I resize manually, the changes are reflected the next time I open the window.  Even if I call `UpdateWindow`, the changes don't reflect.  Is there something I need to send the window so the changes get saved?  Would `RedrawWindow` help?  Thanks?

Comment: The problem is that those APIs explicitly set the window size (and I'm not sure the target application even receives an event - but I could be wrong), so internally the window sizes aren't set to be 'remembered' by the application when the window is un-minimized. I don't know exactly how to solve this, but I'd look into something like the SendMessage API.

Comment: The funny think is, when I resize programmatically, and I manually hover on the window edge until I get the resize mouse cursor, then I simply click down and up (instead of clicking and dragging) and then close the window, the new size that was set programmatically is saved.  Somehow I need to send the window some message, the same that gets sent when you resize manually.

Comment: have you tried Spy++ to see what event is fired when you do so?

Comment: When you use the `SetWindowPos` function, the target window will actually receive a [`WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632653.aspx) with the updated parameters. That's why it moves in the first place. You can see that using Spy++. But that still doesn't fix your problem; see my answer for details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using the **[`GetWindowPlacement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633518.aspx)** and **[`SetWindowPlacement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633544.aspx)** functions instead to retrieve and alter the restored, minimized, and maximized positions of a window. This ensures that the window sizes are properly saved by the application so that they can be restored on the next launch.

Since you're using C#, you'll need to P/Invoke these functions from the Windows API:

```
const int SW_HIDE = 0;
const int SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1;
const int SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2;
const int SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3;

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool GetWindowPlacement(IntPtr hWnd, out WINDOWPLACEMENT lpwndpl);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool SetWindowPlacement(IntPtr hWnd, [In] ref WINDOWPLACEMENT lpwndpl);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct RECT
{
    public int left;
    public int top;
    public int right;
    public int bottom;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct WINDOWPLACEMENT
{
    public int length;
    public int flags;
    public int showCmd;
    public Point ptMinPosition;
    public Point ptMaxPosition;
    public RECT rcNormalPosition;
}
```

Comment: Your input is extremely appreciated, I will try this tomorrow and will update you on the results.  Thank you so much.

Comment: @user577240: Sure, no problem. I realize that's a pretty ugly mess of code, but the problem is that the window has to keep different size information for each possible placement (minimized, normal, and maximized). This should do what you want. Let me know if you need some help calling it from C#.

Comment: NativeMethods.WINDOWPLACEMENT placement = new NativeMethods.WINDOWPLACEMENT(); placement.length = Marshal.SizeOf(placement); NativeMethods.GetWindowPlacement(hwnd, out placement); placement.rcNormalPosition.bottom = width; placement.rcNormalPosition.right = height; placement.rcNormalPosition.left = x; placement.rcNormalPosition.top = y; NativeMethods.SetWindowPlacement(hwnd, ref placement);

Comment: OK I found a solution, thanks to you.  I went to Spy++ like you suggested and started spying on windows I moved manually, what I found is that a WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE and a WM_EXITSIZEMOVE always gets called.  So I simply did a SendMesage twice with WM_ENTER... and WM_EXIT and the sizes of Media Player and control panel got persisted.  Really thanks for your help Cody.